# Who made the weusecoins intro video?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

I really like the weusecoins.com introduction video. Who made the video?

It explains very clearly what bitcoins are, how it is different from other money, and how you can buy and sell bitcoins. They did a great job.

Answer (score 7):

If you would pause the video [a couple seconds from the end](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Um63OQz3bjo&t=1m42s), you could see that the voice is done by Chris Rice, motion graphics by Fabian Rühle, music and sound design by Christian Barth, and production by Stefan Thomas.

Also, if you check the [Active Bounties](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Active_Bounties) page on Bitcoin Wiki, you will see that they made 13622.05 BTC doing it (although it was back when Bitcoins were quite cheap in comparison to what they are now).